# MySQL RDS Incompatible Restore while creating read replica

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds, my.cnf

We have multiple **m5 generation** MySQL RDS instance. The problem we are facing is that while creating read replica for these instances we are repeatedly getting '**incompatible-restore**' error. In the event log of read replica instance we are getting below error :

> Database instance put into incompatible-restore. Your MySql memory
>   setting is inappropriate for the usages

However, if we set the parameter group to '**default-5.7**' then the read replica gets successfully created.

We have found the differences between the current parameter group and 'default-5.7' and tried to make those changes. But still the issue persists.

Comment: In one of the instances, reducing the key_buffer_size helped resolve the issue. But the same trick is not working in the other instances.

Comment: In one of the other instance, reducing the `sort_buffer_size` and `read_rnd_buffer_size` to their default values solved the issue. But still, no idea what is causing it in the first place.

Comment: Did you set it in the primary? Changing those for our primary is pretty risky :/

Comment: @Juliano Sorry, but I did not understand what you meant by "primary"? And why is it risky?

Comment: primary = master in the replication topology, it's risky bc our master is usually under heavy load and I see a possibility of changing those, making performance worse, snowballing and bringing the site down

Comment: What else is different?  `innodb_log_file_size` is rather critical.